# How to get sessionScope attributes on JSTL?

Tags: session, variables, scope, jstl

The task is to retrieve parameters from session via JSTL. The session parameter name is "programId" .

I tried:

```
 <c:if test="${sessionScope.programId != null}" > 
  please execute
  </c:if>
```

Then I tried:

```
 <c:if test="${sessionScope:programId != null}" > please execute </c:if>
```

Here I get: The function applicationScope:programId is undefined

On top I have:

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Oracle has in examples:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL5.html

```
 <c:if test="${applicationScope:booklist == null}" > 
   <c:import url="${initParam.booksURL}" var="xml" />
   <x:parse doc="${xml}" var="booklist" scope="application" />
</c:if>
```

where applicationScope can be swapped by sessionScope.

again "trivialism" complexity drives me nuts. Why corp. examples never work?

Thank You Guys,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reading the wrong tutorial page. The `<c:xxx>` tags does **not** belong to the [JSTL XML taglib](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/x/tld-summary.html) which supports XPath syntax. Instead, it belongs to the [JSTL Core taglib](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) for which the proper tutorial page is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html).

You need to use the normal `${bean.property}` notation instead.

```
<c:if test="${applicationScope.booklist == null}"> 
   <c:import url="${initParam.booksURL}" var="xml" />
   <x:parse doc="${xml}" var="booklist" scope="application" />
</c:if>
```

In normal EL (not XPath!) syntax, the `:` identifies the start of an EL function. See also the [JSTL Functions taglib](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) for several EL function examples for which the tutorial page is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL8.html).

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [Our EL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Answer (score 0):

I don't find in your code you have set your variable `programID` somewhere in your `SessionScope` using EL something like the one shown below.

```
<c:set var="programID" value="SomeValue" scope="session"/>
```

If you indeed didn't set that variable, try setting it first like the above then try the following.

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope:programId != null}" > please execute </c:if>
```

It should work.

Comment: I defined session attribute in controller. I did the same as you suggested and I get : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/viewBank.jsp (line: 39, column: 0) "${sessionScope:programId != null}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${sessionScope:programId != null}]

Comment: The use of **colon** after *sessionScope* [implicit object](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij) is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you have set session in your controller

```
session.setAttribute("programID",someValue);
```

then you should try this

```
${sessionScope.programID} in your jsp
```

which is part of jstl core library

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

and if you are getting exception

```
"${sessionScope:programId != null}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${sessionScope:programId != null}]
```

include jasper.jar in your lib folder
[java brushup](http://coffeewidme.blogspot.in/search/label/Java) for basic concepts of java